# Different DefaultActivities for each flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I am using product flavors for my app and I need different default activities for each product flavor. Since I can not override classes in `main/java`, I need to delete the default activity in this folder and copy a custom version of it to `flavor1/java` and `flavor2/java`.

Now my project does not compile, because it can not find the default activity. In the manifest in `main/java` I did not declare a default `Activity`. Only in the two flavors manifests. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "default activity"? Do you mean the activity that has the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Comment: I cannot reproduce this as it works for me without any problems

Comment: What is your specific compile error? I agree with Rene, this should be fine -- so long as your class exists with the same fully-qualified name in *all* flavors, you should not get a compile error. Make sure that you are using `0.10.x` or higher version of the build tools, though, so manifest merging works, as otherwise, you might get a runtime problem where there is no launcher activity defined in the app's manifest.